# Emacs doesn't recognize OCaml

Tags: emacs, ocaml

I have an issue with emacs.

I've just downloaded it, I have also downloaded Opam and OCaml with the terminal. I am very sure there was no problem with it, and then installed tuareg. I put the `.el` tuareg files where they had to be (in emacs -> site-lisp). But when I open a new file `test.ml`, emacs tells me that the file is not found, and that it is `directory write-protected` and it does not run tuareg mode (it is still in fundamental mode).

I've managed to change the read-only buffer with `C-x C-q` so I can write on the file but when I write `let x = 3;;` and press `C-x C-e`, it does not execute the interpret.

This is my .emacs file :

```lisp
;; Affichage français
(standard-display-european t)

;; Affiche le numéro de ligne et n'affiche pas celui de la colonne
(column-number-mode nil)
(line-number-mode t)

;; Les 'beep' deviennent visibles (et non plus audibles)
(setq visible-bell t)

;; Pour le mode Tuareg
(setq auto-mode-alist (cons '("\\.ml\\w?" . tuareg-mode) auto-mode-alist))
(autoload 'tuareg-mode "tuareg" "Major mode for editing Caml code" t)
(autoload 'camldebug "camldebug" "Run the Caml debugger" t)

;; Pour avoir la coloration syntaxique automatiquement
(global-font-lock-mode 1)

;;Couper sur Ctrl+W
(global-set-key (kbd "C-w" ) 'kill-line) 
;;Copier sur Ctrl+C
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c" ) 'kill-ring-save)
;;Coller sur Ctrl+V
(global-set-key (kbd "C-v" ) 'yank)
;;Annuler sur Ctrl+Z
(global-set-key (kbd "C-z" ) 'undo)
(custom-set-variables
 ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(exec-path (quote ("/usr/bin" "/bin" "/usr/sbin" "/sbin" "/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/bin" "/usr/local/bin"))))
(custom-set-faces
 ;; custom-set-faces was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 )

(setq mac-option-key-is-meta nil)  
(setq mac-command-key-is-meta t)  
(setq mac-command-modifier 'meta)  
(setq mac-option-modifier nil)
```

Comment: That is weird, could you show us your `init.el`? Have you checked your access rights to `test.ml` and your `tuareg.el` (and their directories)? How did you install tuareg? Manually? Through Opam? Through your package manager?

Comment: Qu'est-ce qu'init.el? je croyais que placer le fichier .emacs à la source de mes fichiers suffisait. J'ai installé tuareg manuellement en suivant des instructions sur un site.

Comment: (en anglais s'il te plait, d'autres personnes pourraient avoir le même problème) You have to put your `.emacs` at the root of your home directory. Also, showing it to us could help us understand your problem.

Comment: What happens if you try starting tuareg-mode manually? (`M-x tuareg-mode`)

Comment: when I try to do it manually, this message appears:   "Symbol's value as variable is void: {rtf1ansiansicpg1252cocoartf1561cocoasubrtf400"

Comment: What happens if you try this in a directory that you can write to?

Comment: I don't know how to do that.

Comment: The symbol `{rtf1ansiansicpg1252cocoartf1561cocoasubrtf40` looks like one of your elisp files has been saved as an RTF file (on a Mac) somewhere along the way.

Comment: BTW: don't install packages by hand, use the package manager; `M-x list-packages`. I would recommend that you remove the emacs you installed and start afresh.